# How does HighCharts Series.update() handle a new tooltip positioner?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to update the way the tooltip is positioned for a series. I have an update(), as shown in the code below. The console.log() statements are being executed for the pointFormatter but not in the positioner. It's as if the positioner is being completely ignored. Why is that? Is it not possible to update the tooltip positioner? Is possible some other way?

```
for (var j = 0; j < series.length; j++) {
        bubbleChart.addSeries({data: series[j].data, marker:lineWidth: 0}});
            bubbleChart.series[j].update({
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(37,37,37,0.95)",
                    style: {
                        padding: 10
                    },
                    headerFormat: "",
                    pointFormatter: function () {
                        console.log("RARAR");
                        bubbleRadius = this.shapeArgs.r;
                        return self.getToolTip(parseInt(this.hrr_num));
                    },
                    positioner: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
                        console.log(boxWidth);
                        console.log(boxHeight);
                        console.log(point);
                        return {x: point.plotX + bubbleRadius + 45, y: point.plotY + bubbleRadius + 20};
                    },
                    followPointer: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    shape: "square",
                    hideDelay: 0
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Does the positioner recognize bubbleRadius? can you try adding a console.log for bubbleRadius in the positioner

Comment: It should recognize bubbleRadius, it's in scope (although not in my code snippet). Any console.log() in that positioner does not seem to execute at all. It seems that the entire function does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/dbqktrhk/1/), I have implemented two ways to update `tooltip positioner`.

First one is like what you did which is using `HighCharts.Series.update()` and as expected `console.log('1a');` in my `jsFiddle` does not get called.

Hence I added another piece of code to update the `tooltip.options` by calling `chart.tooltip.options.positioner` and it works.

I noticed that you are accessing `bubbleRadius` variable in the `positioner` function so you might need to change your code a bit in order to implement my second suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option `positioner` under [`series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip) - so updating it won't change anything. There's also no `tooltip.update()` method, so in general you can not update tooltip in run time.

However, for callbacks (like formatters, positioner or tickPositioner) there is a simple trick to make it work, please check: http://jsfiddle.net/dbqktrhk/2/ In short:

1. get default `positioner`:

   ```
   var myPositioner = Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype.getPosition;
   ```
2. use default `positioner` using your variable:

   ```
   tooltip: {
     xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
     shared: true,
     positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
       return myPositioner.call(this, labelWidth, labelHeight, point);
     }
   },
   ```
3. In any moment, update your variable:

   ```
   myPositioner = function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
     console.log('1a');
     return {
       x: 80,
       y: 50
     };
   };
   ```